# Text are in same length, but not aligned after displaying

Tags: html, alignment

Even though text are same length in HTML source, they are not displayed as aligned. I want to display both texts with the same width.

Please see the screenshot

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you'd like to do the alignment simply with the text/font you need to use a [monospaced font type](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monospaced_font). Other possibilities would be to use a table or CSS.

Comment: thanks.it works well with courier New font ( which is monospaced)

Comment: createTeam()
getListOfTeam()
createProject()
getProjectDetails()
createProcess()
getProcess()
getUser()

Comment: List<> fetchTemplateList(User user)
List<> fetchMappingList(User user)

Boolean saveTemplateState(Object obj)
Boolean saveMappingState(Object obj)

List<User> getQCUsers()
assignTemplate(Object obj)
assignMapping(Object obj)

{
Template/Mapping : object 
access : "READ"
actions : {"EXECUTE"}
currentState : "QC_READY"
nextStates : {"QC_IN_PROGRESS}
}





createTeam()
getListOfTeam()
createProject()
getProjectDetails()
createProcess()
getProcess()
getUser()